# Getting the number of elements that are the same at the same index

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, c#-4.0

I have two arrays (both the same length) and I'm trying to iterate through each element in both arrays and test if those elements (that have the **same index**) are equal or not. I want to get the number that are equal and the number that are not equal. I have been able to do it using a `while` loop, but I'm wondering if there's a quicker way with the `System.Linq` extensions?

Here's what I have right now:

```
    var list1 = new List<Color>
        {
            Color.Aqua,
            Color.AliceBlue,
            Color.Beige,
            Color.Red,
            Color.Green,
            Color.White
        };


        var list2 = new List<Color>
        {
            Color.Red,
            Color.BurlyWood,
            Color.Beige,
            Color.Azure,
            Color.Green,
            Color.Magenta
        };

        var enumFirst = list1.GetEnumerator();
        var enumSecond = list2.GetEnumerator();

        var equal = 0;
        var notEqual = 0;

        while (enumFirst.MoveNext() && enumSecond.MoveNext())
        {
            var colorFirst = enumFirst.Current;
            var colorSecond = enumSecond.Current;

            if (colorFirst == colorSecond)
                equal++;
            else
                notEqual++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Elements that are equal: " + equal);
        Console.WriteLine("Elements that are not equal: " + notEqual);
```

The output is:

```
Elements that are equal: 2
Elements that are not equal: 4
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use `Zip`.

```
var equal = list1.Zip(list2, (l1, l2) => l1 == l2).Count(x => x);
var notEqual = list1.Count() - equal;
```

`Zip` will skip all remaining elements if one of the lists has no more elements to enumerate (lists have different number of elements):

> If the input sequences do not have the same number of elements, the method combines elements until it reaches the end of one of the sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not quicker, but definitely one-liner:

```
var areequal = list1.Select((x, i) => list2[i] == x);
var equals = areequal.Count(x => x);
var notequals = areequal.Count(x => !x);
```

Using `Select` you can select if elemest are equal or not, and then by using count, count each group. This method will work only if list2 is at least same size as list1 (but in question is note that lists are same size)

But if in some case these lists are of different size change first line to:

```
var areequal = list1.Take(Math.Min(list2.Count, list.Count))
                                                      .Select((x, i) => list2[i] == x);
```

`Take` will make you sure that all processed elements from `list1` are the same size as `list2`.